# Value is 0 on server, but on localhost it's getting a Value

Tags: php, html

So basically, on my localhost it's running perfectly fine and Answer is getting assigned to a value, but as soon as I upload it to the server it's saying my $Answer variable is equal to 0 rather than the value it should have assigned to it. My guess it was the php version, but I'm not 100% sure.

for instance:

on localhost i have  `mathQuiz.php?Question=5+x+8&Answer=40&guess=40`

while on the server I have `mathQuiz.php?Question=5+x+8&Answer=0&guess=40`

```
<html> 
<body> 
<form action="mathQuiz.php" method="get"> 
<h3> Math Quiz</h3> 
<?php 

$Question = $_GET['Question']; 

$guess = $_GET['guess']; 

$Answer = $_GET['Answer']; 


if (!isset($Question)) { 

$Question = rand(1,9) .' x '. rand(1,9); 
$Answer = $Question[0] * $Question[-1]; 
echo $Question; 
} 

if (isset($_GET['reset'])) { 
$guess = NULL; 
$Question = rand(1,9). ' x ' .rand(1,9); 
$Answer = $Question[0] * $Question[-1]; 
echo "<br/>"; 
echo $Question; 
} 

if (isset($_GET['guess'])) { 
if ($Answer == $_GET['guess']) { 
$message = "Question Correct!"; 
echo $message; 
echo "<br/>"; 
$Question = rand(1,9) .' x '. rand(1,9); 
$Answer = $Question[0] * $Question[-1]; 
echo "Try a another! ". "<br/>" . $Question; 
} 

else if ($Answer != $_GET['guess'] and (!isset($_GET['reset']))){ 
$message = "Question Incorrect"; 
echo $message; 
echo "<br/>"; 
if (isset($_GET['guess'])) { 
echo <<< HERE 
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Again?"> 
<br/> 

HERE; 
} 
} 
} 
if (isset($_GET['button'])){ 
$button = $_GET['button']; 
echo $Question; 
} 


?> 


<input type="hidden" name="Question" value="<?php echo($Question); ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="Answer" value="<?php echo($Answer); ?>"> 
<input type="text" name="guess" value="<?php echo($guess); ?>"> 
<input type="submit" value="Guess"> 
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset"> 
<br/> 
<br/> 
<a href="index.html">Back to home</a> 

</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: what shall this line `$Answer = $Question[0] * $Question[-1]` do? `$Question` is a string there, not an array.

Comment: the `<form ..>` should not be before `<body>`. This is invalid html.

Comment: I fixed that, I see your point about how it's a string. Why's it working on localhost like this then? @Jeff

Comment: it's a string because `rand(1,9) .' x '. rand(1,9)` results in a string. `$Question[-1]` produces a `Notice Uninitialized string offset: -1 on line number xy`. So Answer will be undefined, hence 0.

Comment: So my guess is a different setting of error_reporting/handling.

Comment: So to fix it I should convert that string into an array?

Comment: Yes. Make it an array from the start: `$Question = [rand(1,9), rand(1,9)];` Then adjust the rest of your code. (`$Question[-1]` will then be `$Question[1]`,..)

Comment: What version of php are you using on both servers? Not the same one, right?
Negative string offsets are now supported after PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting different behaviours probably because of different PHP versions running on your localhost and on your second server.

negative string offsets are now supported (Since PHP 7.1)
as you can see in this RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/negative-string-offsets

Also you can play using different PHP versions using some php sandbox [like this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) and you will see that using any version prior to 7.1 will give you 0 as response and the following notice:

> Notice Uninitialized string offset: -1